# Toggle appendChild if doesnt exist and removeChild if exist

Tags: javascript

I want to have a button which toggles element in the document.
I don't want to use class display: none if/else statement. Instead, I want to appendChild if it doesn't exist and if it exists, then I want to removeChild.
There is an idea of what I want to achieve, but I have some problem there. The element is shown, but on next click, it is not removed, instead, I get multiple copies of it. (I think so). Please, no jQuery. Vanilla JavaScript only. Don't know is it important, but `my-element` is HTML `<template>`.

```
<body>
    <button id="my-button">Toggle</button>
    <template id="my-element">
        <div>
            Some content
        </div>
    </template>
<script>
    let element = document.getElementById('my-element');
    let content = element.content;

    function toggle () {
        if (document.body.contains(content)) {
            document.body.removeChild(content);
        } else {
            document.body.appendChild(content);
        }
    }

    let button = document.getElementById('my-button');
    button.addEventListener('click', toggle, false);
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Please add the minimal HTML to make a runable example.

Comment: `removeChild` only works with direct children. If `content` exists as a deeper descendant, `document.body.removeChild` isn't going to do it. You'll need to find the parent node of `content` and call `removeChild` on that.

Comment: So, it matters in what DOM nesting level `my-button` appears? In my example i put `my-button` in the same level, but in reality it is nested down in DOM tree. (inside multiple parent DIV's.)

Comment: No, not `my-button`. `content`.

Comment: But I believe `my-element` in my case is right into `body`. As I put my `<template id="my-element">` right before closing `</body>` tag and when I do `document.body.appendChild` I think it is appended right to the body. Sorry, I am total newbie in this stuff right now. :)

Comment: @Dzintars This is your problem: `document.body.contains(content))` see my answer for a better statement. `content` isn't a node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should understand that `template` exists outside of the loaded DOM, so no matter where you physically locate it in the code really won't make any difference later. Also, understand that when you want to access content of a `template`, you use `.content`, but after that content is injected into the DOM, it's not `template.content` anymore, it's part of the DOM.

So, you can't search the document for template `.content` because, after it gets inserted, it won't be template content in your document, it will be actual DOM content. You'll need some way of identifying it and a class is the simplest way.

Also, the **[documentation on templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)** says that you bring template content into the document with **[`document.importNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/importNode)**, which you aren't using.

Next, always remember that **[`.removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild)** does what its name implies, it removes child elements. `document.body.removeChild()` can therefore only remove children of the `body` element, so you need to remember this. Your code may be OK for finding the imported node as a child of `body`, but that may not always be the case depending on where you inserted it. The code below dynamically locates the imported content's parent node and will always remove it, regardless of where it winds up being located in the DOM.

Lastly, **and this is very important**, although you have indicated that you don't want to hide/show the element and would rather append it and remove it, **doing so is very expensive in terms of performance**. Every time you add or remove an element from the DOM, the entire DOM has to be rebuilt and the node(s) you remove don't necessarily get removed from memory even though they are not present in the DOM anymore. So, do this at your own risk. It's actually much better (from a performance standpoint) to simply hide/show content.

```js
let element = document.getElementById('my-element');

function toggle () {
  // Attempt to reference the element in the document, not the template content
  var imported = document.querySelector(".imported");
    
   // Check for the element, not the template content
   if (document.body.contains(imported)) {
     // Element exists, call removeChild on its parent
     imported.parentNode.removeChild(imported);
   } else {
     // Use .importNode to bring template content in:
     document.body.appendChild(document.importNode(element.content, true));
   }
}

document.getElementById('my-button').addEventListener('click', toggle);
```

```html
<button id="my-button">Toggle</button>
<template id="my-element">
  <div class="imported">Some content</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Really BIG BIG positive karma wagon for deep explanation! Works like a charm! Second solution also looks good, but I must select one. I will now modify this to enable option when clicking outside of my-element it also removes.

Comment: Hi, You are telling that appendChild is expensive in terms of performance. But... as I dig thru Web Components, appendChild and importNode is the only methods to manipulate with my components.

Comment: @Dzintars I'm saying that you need to be mindful of when and how often you use them, not to not use them at all. Often, it's better to just show/hide something that to modify the DOM structure repeatedly. In many cases, it's much more efficient not to use templates and just include the content in your document from the start, but just style that content so that it's hidden initially. Then you can just show it when you need to.

Comment: Thank You for deep insights!